# How do i hide columns with formula output 0 without changing the formula to value

Tags: excel, vba, hide, formula

I'm new to this and I am trying to unhide all columns then hide the columns that contain on one row the number "0", the problem is that number is a result of a formula.

This is what I tried:

```vba
Sub main()
Rows("1:1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Dim Col As Range
For Each Col In Columns("E:EX")
    For Each Row In Rows("9:9")
        Col.Hidden = Col.Find("0", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, , , False) Is Nothing
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

The result of the code above is that all those columns(E:Ex) get hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, kinda but few details / improvements to be made

```
Private Sub hide_zeroes()

  Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Your sheet name") '<- edit me
  Dim lc as Long: lc = ws.Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last active Column
  Dim i as Long

  For i = 1 to lc 'from first till last colummn
     If ws.Cells(9, i) = "0" Then 'if 9th row of Column [i] is 0 Then
         ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hide entire column
     End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

1. It's good practice to end your `For` loops with the variable you're looping. Helps to keep the code readable and makes you avoid unnecessary errors in nested loops

   ```
   For i = 1 to 99
      'some code
   Next i 'note the i <-
   ```
2. You don't need to check whether it's a formula, just check if the value inside the cell
3. It's good practice to declare variable names for every variable you're using, or better yet, use `Option Explicit` *(first line of your code)* to enable something akin to a "strict mode"

Comment: i just added "Rows("1:1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False" because i wanted to unhide everithing before the rest of the code.

Comment: oops my bad, overlooked that in your initial code. Either way, glad it helped :)

Comment: Just swap the .Hidden values as True and False other way around

Comment: Worked like this:

Comment: Sub hide_zeroes()

  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Retete") '<- edit me
  Dim lc As Long: lc = ws.Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last active Column
  Columns("E:kx").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Dim i As Long
  
  For i = 1 To lc 'from first till last colummn
     If ws.Cells(9, i) = "0" Then 'if 9th row of Column [i] is 0 Then
         ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'show entire column
     End If
  Next i

End Sub